# C# loop on SettingsProperty

Tags: c#

I have multiple checkbox that are checked if application settings are true and update the setting value if they are checked/unchecked by the user.
My issue is that there are lot of checkbox and settings, is there a way to do a loop in order to have less lines ?

```
checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
checkBox1.Click += delegate {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1 = checkBox1.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
};
checkBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting2;
checkBox2.Click += delegate {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Setting2 = checkBox2.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
};
checkBox3.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting3;
checkBox3.Click += delegate {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Setting3 = checkBox3.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
};
```

Thank you for your propositions.

Comment: You could place all your checkboxes in a `panel` then iterate over the `Controls` of that panel , check their `type` and if type is checkbox do the logic.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is

1- Place all the checkboxes on a panel, say cbPanel

2- assign click event to all check box items on the panel

```
foreach(cb in cbPanel.Controls)
{
  if(cb is CheckBox cbItem)
  {
       cbItem.Click += Main_Click; // once added this line it will automatically create the click event on the form. 
  }
}
```

3- Delete all the settings1-2-3 in the  in Settings.Default file and add one Setting property in Dictionary

and now since we assigned the the same click event to all checkboxes on the panel whatever checkbox you change it's state it will hit to the `Main_click` event

4-

```
private void Main_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is CheckBox cb)) return;

         // here add some  logic so that if 
         //Properties.Settings.Default.Setting contains Key (checkbox name) update  
         //value else add key and value and then save..

    }
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I just Debugged this and worked fine ( Add Your `Checkboxes` into a `Panel` :)

It's just for three checkbox and three Setting with exact same name as you provided in the question.

```
 foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)// all checkboxes in a panel
  {
      int i = 1;
      var val = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["Setting" + i.ToString()];
             if (c is CheckBox)
                {
                  if ((!((CheckBox)c).Checked))
                    {
                      ((CheckBox)c).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(val.DefaultValue);
                            ((CheckBox)c).Click += delegate
                            {
                                val.DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)c).Checked;
                                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                            };
                    }

                 }
               i++;           
   }
```